# Proper way to initialize property of class

Tags: php

I have a class with a property. The way I implemented is that the object is initialized in the constructor and its properties are initialized separately inside another method. So here's what it looks like -

```
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php') 
class myclass {
    private $mailer;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
    }
    public function set($host, $to) {
      var_dump($this->mailer) // This returns object structure
      $this->mailer->Host = $host;
      $this->mailer->to = $to;
   }
}
```

However, I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" notice even though mailer property is already initialized with PHPMailer.(I tested with var_dump as shown in the code) I could suppress it with "@", but I'm looking for better solution if there's any. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the full error.

Comment: The rest is just the filename where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to store the mailer from your constructor but you do not have a variable called $mailer set.

Also in PHPMailer everything starts capitalized so To would also have to be capitalized.

You are also missing semicolumns.

```
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

class myClass {
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
    }

    public function set($host, $to) {
      var_dump($this->mailer);
      $this->mailer->Host = $host;
      $this->mailer->To = $to;
   }
}
```

Then you wanna access it like this.

```
$test = new myClass();
$test->set("asdf", "swdf@sdf.sd");
```

Comment: Sorry, my actually code does have $mailer, mistakenly type $a at declaration when I post. For To property, I switch it to addAddress method. But still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @user30646 It looks like the constructor is behaving strange then, could you try and put the $this->mailer = new PHPMailer; in the set function?

Comment: That resolve the issue. But turns out that, in somewhere in my code, I was calling set method without providing all the parameters. After fixing that, the issue is fixed. I don't know how that relates to the Error I'm getting but it fixes the error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user30646 You're welcome, if my answer gave you the answer please mark it as answered.